# Does unittest allow single case/suite testing through "setup.py test"?

Tags: python, unit-testing, setuptools

I'm a newbie when it comes to python unit testing, but I'm eager to learn!
I just read `python setup.py test` can run all suites derived from unittest classes. I wonder if I also can use setup.py to run a single suite and/or a single test case, maybe adding some modifier to the previous command like `python setup.py tests suitename`. If so, can you please point me to any docs/examples?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `setup.py test` runner is rather limited; it only supports letting you specify a specific module. The documentation for the command-line switches is given when you use the `--help` switch:

```
python setup.py test --help
Common commands: (see '--help-commands' for more)
  [ ... cut ... ]

Options for 'test' command:
  --test-module (-m)  Run 'test_suite' in specified module
  --test-suite (-s)   Test suite to run (e.g. 'some_module.test_suite')

  [ ... more cut ... ]
```

so `python setup.py test -m your.package.tests.test_module` would limit running the tests from the `test_module.py` file only.

All the `test` command does, really, is make sure your egg has been built already, extract the `test_suite` value from `setup()` metadata, configure a test loader that understands about zipped eggs, then run the [`unittest.main()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.main) function.

If you need to run a single test only, have already built your egg, are not running this with a zipped egg, then you can also just use the [`unittest` command line interface](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface), which does pretty much everything else:

```
python -m unittest yourpackage.tests.TestClass.test_method
```

would instruct `unittest` to only run a very specific test method.

Answer (score 27):

You guys are all wrong, `setup.py test` can be used with the `-s` option the same way `python -m unittest` does:

```
cd root_of_your_package
python setup.py test -s tests.TestClass.test_method
```

Comment: All you need to do is import the test cases inside tests/__init__.py - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### setup.py test

setup.py test is not that flexible, but here's an alternative:

### The unittest module can run specific test methods

[From the Documentation on unittest](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface)

The unittest module can be used from the command line to run tests from modules, classes or even individual test methods:

```
python -m unittest test_module1 test_module2
python -m unittest test_module.TestClass
python -m unittest test_module.TestClass.test_method
```

You can pass in a list with any combination of module names, and fully qualified class or method names.

You can run tests with more detail (higher verbosity) by passing in the -v flag:

```
python -m unittest -v test_module
```

For a list of all the command-line options:

```
python -m unittest -h
```

Answer (score 1):

in case of pytest run specific test:

```
python setup.py test --addopts tests/jobs/test_data_monitoring.py::TestDataMonitoring::test_dataframe__bulk_update
```

Comment: That is not fully correct. If you specify a single test like that pytest will change the working directory to the `tests/jobs/`. It will not include `conftest.py` files on the levels of `test` and `test/jobs` that could be a significant side effect.

The correct way to run a single test is to specify the `-k` key.

Comment: this is to run unittest with pytest as runner. not sure if conftest.py applies then

Answer (score 0):

In case you use [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) for unit testing you can run a file directly by avoiding the `setup.py` file.

Running all tests for me is:

```
python setup.py test
```

Running a specific test:

```
pytest --pyargs path/to/test.py
```

Hope it helps.

(I know this post is already a bit old, but I came here looking for running a way to run pytest tests alone, figured it might be of use to someone)